# How can I make custom static widgets/areas on my homepage?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I'd like 2 areas on my homepage which will be static but can be editable with tinyMCE or whatever editor WP uses instead of hardcoding HTML in the Widget editing area.

What would be a way I can go about doing this? For both boxes, I want an image, heading, and paragraph text along with 2 buttons below.

It seems https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ is what I need, but is it really what I need or is there something built-in that I can use for this?

Also, would I have to edit the homepage HTML to create those 2 divs and then add custom wp code to fetch them, or something of that nature?

Visually this is an example of one of the 2 areas that I need. They're identical but should be separately editable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can achieve this easily with the plugin you mentioned, Advanced Custom Fields.

But if you can code a bit, there is a way to easily implement this with no plugin.  You can create a metabox with custom fields and attach it to the homepage custom post type, if that's how you have it set up, or to the page that's assigned as the front page for your site.

More info on Metaboxex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

[Here is a tutorial on how to create Metaboxes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/).

I use this great plugin to build metaboxes and theme options, check it out, it's free and a great tool for any Wordpress developer: https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

Comment: What's the benefit of option tree vs metaboxes or are you managing metaboxes with that plugin only? And, what do you suggest is the best way to actually have a 'static' home page with custom boxes all over the place in terms of setting it up? Make it a static page or update the code, and if so what file would it be?

Comment: I use optiontree to build custom theme options and metaboxes because it offers a variety of field options that function well presented in a nice UI. Not sure if I understand your questions correctly, but you can create a custom post type and set it as your homepage, or create a regular page and in Settings -> Reading set that as the front page of your site. See this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page